# Node.js chat bot generating same random number?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is for Twitch.tv. If someone types !random in the chat, the bot will reply with a random number from 1-100. But it's currently only returning the same number (e.g. 58) over and over again. Any help with this? Cheers.

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

var canSendMessage = true;
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
if(message === "!random" && canSendMessage ) {
canSendMessage = false;

client.say("shred", rand.toString());

setTimeout(function(){ canSendMessage = true }, 2000);
}});
```

Comment: Well, you're only ever generating the random number once.

Comment: @bejado How would i generate it infinite times?

Comment: You need to generate a new random number with `Math.random()` inside the function that replies to the !random message.

Comment: Please leave the original question in place so that others can search for it if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the Twitch API before, but I'd imagine you need to do something like this:

```
var canSendMessage = true;
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
    if (message === "!random" && canSendMessage) {
        canSendMessage = false;
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        client.say("shred", rand.toString());
        setTimeout(function() { canSendMessage = true }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Notice how `Math.random()` is called for each chat message received, to generate a new random number each time.